# MySQL 5.7 смена пароля

Tags: mysql, пароль, password

Не могу сменить пароль, mysql 5.7

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('123456') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> \q
sudo service mysql start
```

Однако никакого эффекта, при попытке соединиться:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Если на локалке делаете, то скачайте какой-ниудь `Navicat` например, там легко менять и добавлять пользователей и их пароли. Да там и на хост можно подключиться.

Comment: На всякий случай покажите `select Host, User from mysql.user;`

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL версии 5.7 некоторые способы смены пароля были объявилены устаревшими и перестали работать. Хорошим тоном, по-видимому, стало использовать такой синтаксис:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = password_option;
```

В опции `password_option` можно передавать пароль как в виде строки, так и обёрнутым в конкретную функцию хэширования, причём поведение хэширующих функций меняется в зависимости от минорной версии 5.7.x.

Подробнее в документации: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html

Также можно вместо `UPDATE USER` использовать `ALTER USER`:

```
ALTER USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret_password';
```

Comment: При вызове этих комманд получаю ошибку: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` . Ха-ха

Comment: Интересненько... Как-то не по правилам Кода