# Как поменять пароль у root'a в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет
При установка mysql

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Должен запрашиваться пароль для рутового пользователя, но у меня почему-то не было этого.
Т.е. сейчас можно зайти в БД через терминал

> sudo mysql

Но как мне подключиться к бд удаленно, например, через рута, если я не знаю его пароля?
Посоветовали утилиту  **mysql_secure_installation**
Установил новый пароль, перезагрузил сервер, но опять при попытке подключится через рута

> mysql -uroot -p

после ввода, установленного пароля, пишет аксес динаед
Поэтому возникает вопрос, как можно еще поменять пароль и почему вообще так происходит(почему при установке не было ввода его)
Заранее благодарю за ответы 
P.S. Простите, если описание корявое :)

Comment: А позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вам подключаться удалённо? Вроде для большинства ситуаций достаточно локального подключения

Comment: @andreymal да даже неудаленное, например подключение из какого нить приложения, там указывается пользователь и пароль для подключения, я указываю root, а пароль какой?
Вот мне и нужно как-то установить пароль

Comment: Все нормальные приложения обычно умеют подключаться локально без всяких паролей, главное — чтобы имя пользователя совпадало с именем системного пользователя, в котором запущено приложение. Если ваше не умеет — у вас плохое приложение, а если у вас бардак в именах, то у вас плохая организация сервера :)

Answer (score 0):

Было ранее
[MySQL 5.7 смена пароля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621725/mysql-5-7-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

```
ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, но как создать пользователя я знаю, у меня вопрос как поменять пароль у рута, даже не поменять, а создать, так как у меня его нет